# A link to APK file does not open in chrome browser

Tags: android, google-chrome, mobile, download, apk

I have a use case where I would like to distribute link to my APK file to users via text or WhatsApp message or through other(slack, skype) channels.  But, when I click on that link on mobile, it does open chrome and nothing happens. While if I try this on other browsers, then the links opens.

Can you please help me how can I make sure that the chrome prompts me to download the file instead of going mute.?